# subtracting two dates via moment results in wrong year

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Hey folks running into a problem with dates that I would love an extra set of eyes on. Any help would be appreciated.

**Problem:** I have a future event which will occur on a certain date, when I subtract the future event date from the current date I get a year that is in the past and an extra day.

```
let evenDate = "12 08 2019, 12:00 am";
let eventFormat = "MM DD YYYY, h:mm a";
const futureEvent = moment(evenDate, eventFormat).utc();
const now = moment().utc();
const timeDiff = moment(futureEvent - now).utc(); // also tried futureEvent.diff(now)

let daysLeft:  moment(timeDiff).format('D') - 1; // have to subtract 1


console.log('futureEvent:', futureEvent);
// Sun Dec 08 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)


console.log('now:', now);
// Wed Dec 04 2019 10:18:26 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)


console.log('timeDiff:', timeDiff);
// Sun Jan 04 1970 06:41:33 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
```

Comment: `let daysLeft =  moment(timeDiff).format('D') - 1; ` is that a typo or your actual code is `:`  ?

Comment: Eldar that is the actual code without the - 1 I was getting an extra day when displaying the days left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let evenDate = "12 08 2019, 12:00 am";
let eventFormat = "MM DD YYYY, h:mm a";
const futureEvent = moment(evenDate, eventFormat);
const now = moment();
const timeDiff = moment.duration(futureEvent.diff(now)); 

let daysLeft = timeDiff.asDays();

const disp = document.getElementById("display");

disp.innerText = daysLeft.toFixed(); // 3.0123 
console.log("futureEvent:", futureEvent.toString());
```

Same code i just get rid of `.utc()`s. used `.duration()` and for getting dates used `.asDays()`.
[Pen](https://codepen.io/3ldar/pen/yLyNyKo?editors=1011)